# Angularjs-read more custom directive not work with ng-bind-html directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

These are my custom directive for read more and to_trusted (for convert to html).

```
psp.directive('hmRead', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        scope:{
            hmtext : '@',
            hmlimit : '@',
            hmfulltext:'@',
            hmMoreText:'@',
            hmLessText:'@',
            hmMoreClass:'@',
            hmLessClass:'@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/common/read-more.html',
        controller : function($scope){
              $scope.toggleValue=function(){

                    if($scope.hmfulltext == true)
                        $scope.hmfulltext=false;
                    else if($scope.hmfulltext == false)
                        $scope.hmfulltext=true;
                    else
                        $scope.hmfulltext=true;
              }        
        }
    };
});

psp.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);
```

calling in html.

```
 <hm-read hmtext="{{data.content}}" ng-bind-html="data.content| to_trusted" hmlimit="100" hm-more-text="read more" hm-less-text="read less"></hm-read>
```

If iI remove `ng-bind-html` then read more is working fine but with `ng-bind-html` directive **readmore** directive is not working.

Answer (score 0):

the logic of your directive is a little unclear as an **Read-More** directive especially usage of **templateUrl** in your directive, **hmfulltext**  parameter and **ng-bind-html**.

By the way I used your directive by fake template in your directive:

```
template: '<p>template that is set in your directive</p>',
```

and fake content scope variable as following:

```
$scope.data={};
$scope.data.content = '<p>template that passed into directive</p>';
```

by this fake template's your directive work correctly

[Online Execution](https://jsbin.com/yijasal/1/edit?html,js,output)

It reveals that the problem is in either **'partials/common/read-more.html'** template or **data.content** scope variable. you can look for the bug in these places.